# Use cached data on an action filter, to avoid another execution of an action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, action-filter

I would like to do the following (i will split in two points):

- Before execution of the action, if the viewmodel is in cache then return the view and the viewmodel without execute the action.
- If is not in the cache, continue with the execution of the action, and reach the OnActionExecuted to put the viewmodel in cache.

How could i return the view and the viewmodel without execute the action (first point)?

This is the code. My doubt indicated with ???????:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
   //IF the viewmodel exists dont execute the action again
   if (filterContext.HttpContext.Cache["viewmodel"]!=null)
   {
      filterContext.Result=???????
   }
   base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
}

public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
{
    //Cast de model
    ContentDetailVM model = (ContentDetailVM)filterContext.Controller.ViewData.Model;
    filterContext.HttpContext.Cache.Insert("viewmodel", model);
    //we're asking for a close section
    if (model.CurrentSection.HideAccess == true)
    {
         //pass to the client some flag in order to show the div
         filterContext.Controller.ViewData["showoverlaylayer"]=true;
    }
    base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);     
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Best Regards.

Jose.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    var model = filterContext.HttpContext.Cache["viewmodel"];
    if (model != null)
    {
        var result = new ViewResult();
        result.ViewData.Model = model;
        filterContext.Result = result;
    }
}
```

Comment: One question, im getting the error cause im using a master page. Do you know if i need to assign more properties to the ViewResult that im creating? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Aparently the problem is more complex... The thing is that this action filter is for one "widget" thats inside other page (using a render action) and this page is into a master. I think i need to set not only the master but the page where this widget is included, etc... Thanks

Comment: @Jose3d, yes it is more complex then :-) By the way have you considered using the `[OutputCache]` attribute?

Comment: Hi Darin, [OutputCache] is not enough in my case the "widget view" changes depending on model properties and some security stuff too. Anyway i solved it changing a little the code that you give me, just do "var result=new PartialViewResult()" and it worked. Thanks for all the great tips!

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Hello Darin, I have made a lot of call on inside ACtionFilterAttribute. Can I cache them in asp.net